# Writing GPIO Interrupt Handlers for LPC1769 Cortex M3

Tags: c, embedded, cortex-m, lpc

Is there a simple GPIO Interrupt example for the ARM Cortex-M3?

I have written some code, however somehow the interrupt does not seem to fire:

```
#include "LPC17xx.h"
#include "lpc17xx_pinsel.h"
#include "lpc17xx_gpio.h"

void EINT3_IRQHandler(void) {
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(EINT3_IRQn);
    puts("triggered");  // fired
}

int main() {
    /** ... **/
    /** ... **/

    // listen for input on INPUT pin @ GPIO port 1, pin 31
    PINSEL_CFG_Type PinCfg;
    PinCfg.Funcnum = 0;
    PinCfg.OpenDrain = 0;
    PinCfg.Pinmode = 0;
    PinCfg.Portnum = 1;
    PinCfg.Pinnum = 31;
    PINSEL_ConfigPin(&PinCfg);

    GPIO_SetDir(port, 1 << pin, 0);

    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EINT3_IRQn);

    while(1);       // wait

    /** ... **/
    /** ... **/

    return 0;
}
```

I have been searching online / GitHub for a simple GPIO interrupt example for the LPC1769 Cortex M3, but it yields no results.  It appears however that:

1. the GPIO interrupt of interest is `EINT_3`.
2. the IRQ handler `EINT3_IRQHandler` gets overwritten, when defined in user code.

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you add EINT3_IRQHandler to your interrupt vector table? If you didn't, the compiler will not know that it is called and therefore remove it. Also, the interrupt won't get triggered by the hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the LPC17xx, you have interrupt enable registers for Port 0 and 2, see UM10360.pdf chapter 9.5.6 for reference. You have no GPIO interrupts on Port 1, 3 and 4 - you code appears to use Port 1.31, which cannot have GPIO interrupts.

In the exception handler 
you must not forget to clear the intterupt flags in `IO0IntClear` and `IO2IntClear`. Failing to do so would re-trigger the handler function otherwise, even when using `NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ()`.

The "correct" name for the handler function may depend on your toolchain.

Comment: Great!!  Thanks.  Realized that the peripheral was connected to port 1.  Since this port doesnt have interrupt support, therefore it didn't trigger.  Note: Use only port 0 or port 2 to trigger interrupts.

Answer (score -1):

> the IRQ handler EINT3_IRQHandler gets overwritten, when defined in user code.

I do not know that specific device, but I suppose you need to call these instructions from priviledged mode. My guess is these instructions don't do anything if called from user mode.

Comment: There is no priviledged mode in a Cortex M, unless you manually enable the MPU.